# I can't add a controller in mvc 4 code first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I cant add a controller, it says:

> Unable to retrieve Metadata for "Diets.Models.Usuario" The Property "ProgramaDietaID" cannot be configurated as Navigation Property. The property must be a valid Entity and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection Properties the type must implement ICollection where T is a valid entity type.

**I don't figure out what I'm doing wrong, the roles between "Usuario" and "ProgramaDieta" entities are one-to-many.**

```
public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int UsuarioID { get; set; } 

    [Display(Name = "Name:")]//lo que mostrara el titulo del campo la Vista.
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$")]//para que acepte solo letras y no carac. alfanumericos.
    [Required]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProgramaDieta> ProgramaDietas { get; set; }
}

public class ProgramaDieta
{
   [Key]
   public int ProgramaDietaID { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("UsuarioID")]
   public int UsuarioID { get; set; }
   public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

Context Class

```
public class MejoraConProgramasContext:DbContext
{
    public MejoraConProgramasContext()
        : base("MejoraConProgramasContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProgramaDieta> Programas { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ForeignKey` is improperly attached to the `int UsuarioID` property instead of the `virtual Usuario Usuario`.

Comment: Hehe, nice catch. I kept staring at this.

Comment: I was staring for some time, too :)

Comment: Thanks for the try, but the problem keeps, after delete Foreign key form UsuarioID and put in Usuario Usuario :(, I believe is a mapping entities problem.